# combination of leal and shift in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, att

Here leal and shift together compute (z*48) where z is represented by %eax. 
Could someone explain me how do these work to get the final result?
And also why cant we use (mull $48, %eax)?

```
leal (%eax, %eax, 2), %eax    //z*3
sall $4, %eax                 //z*48
```

Comment: (2 + 1) * 2^4 = 3 * 16 = 48

Comment: `leal (%eax, %eax, 2), %eax` is eax = eax + 2 * eax or eax = eax * 3. If you  shift a value left 1 bit you effectively double the value. shift 4 you are multiplying by 16 (2 * 2 * 2 * 2). So `sall $4, %eax` multiplies what is already in %eax by 16. So eax = (3 * 16) * eax .  Reviewing an instruction set [MUL](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_210.html) or unsigned multiply doesn't take an immediate value. On a side note [IMUL](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_138.html) (signed multiply does). That is just a limitation of the x86 instruction set.

Comment: Also mul/imul can be **much** slower, than doing lea+sal. (hmm.. on latest CPU, and multiplying only by 48 it wouldn't be maybe that bad, but in early days of computing this may go as far as tenfold slower .. dare you profile? :) To have first hand experience and to learn profiling...)

Comment: @Ped7g: It's easier to look up the latency for different microarchitectures in [Agner Fog's tables](http://agner.org/optimize/) than to actually design a microbenchmark that tests this correctly.  Intel SnB-family CPUs have 3-cycle latency for `imul r,r, i`, so it would save a uop but cost an extra 1 cycle of latency.  AMD has slightly slower multiply.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: the multi-operand forms of `imul` only produce the low half of the result, which is the same whether the inputs are interpreted as signed or not.  So there's no need for a separate `mul r,r,i` instruction; it could be an alternate mnemonic for the same opcode.  IDK why they picked `imul` as the mnemonic for the low-half version with multiple explicit operands.

Comment: I didn't say it couldn't be used. I gave them a link to the instruction set, as I would hope they would read it and realize it may serve their purpose. The instruction set clearly states that it CAN be used for unsigned multiplication. I left it up to the reader to go there. The only thing I regret leaving out was the link to the [LEA](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/LEA.html) instruction.

Comment: @PeterCordes : I didn't state it but that was a direct response to the OPs question `And also why cant we use (mull $48, %eax)?` It doesn't work because the x86 architecture doesn't allow an immediate with MUL specifically. That is the simple truth. Thus the links to an instruction set reference. My first comment was to give an idea how to approach the first part of the question, the next comment was to answer the second part.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Oh right, I missed that part of the question.  That makes sense now.  I tend to stop reading once I see what's generally being asked, and then just go and see if it's already been answered adequately.